# Referring to someone's home in sonkeigo

Tags: word-choice, usage, connotation

I know that *sonkeigo* for someone's home is お宅, but since the word オタク has a quite negative connotation, I am worried that お宅 might not be appropriate, especially in spoken language (because there is no way to differentiate お宅 vs オタク). Hence, is there any alternative to お宅, or do I have to use this word really carefully?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am worried that お宅 might not be appropriate, especially in spoken language (because there is no way to differentiate お宅{たく} vs オタク).

That is not true at all because people can always tell which one you meant from the context of the conversation.

I could not think of a single example where there could be that kind of confusion because  the difference in meaning is just huge between the two words.

Besides 「お宅{たく}」, you can use 「ご自宅{じたく}」 or 「お住{す}まい」.  All are good words to know.

There exist bigger words such as 「尊宅{そんたく}」, 「尊家{そんか}」, etc., but those are rarely, if ever, used.