# What's the difference between 家 and 宅?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words

I saw these two kanjis while writing down some words, and they appeared to have the same meaning.

Normally I heard うち as home but they (いえ and たく) got translated as home-house as well

so I'm wondering about the differences, and can they be replaced with うち?

Answer (score 4):

For the difference between うち and いえ, please see: [What is the difference between いえ and うち?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3726/5010)

宅【たく】 is not used as a standalone noun. This kanji is used mainly as part of longer compounds such as 自宅, 邸宅 or 宅地. Or did you hear お宅【おたく】? お宅 is an honorific expression used to refer to someone else's home respectfully. お宅 is also a blunt and/or nerdy second-person pronoun used by some. See: [When is it appropriate to use お宅 to refer to the second-person?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6986/5010), [Referring to someone's home in sonkeigo](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42436/5010) and [Why is the word オタク written in katakana?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46870/5010)